# Why does my implementation of L1- regularization give poor performance?

Tags: python, neural-network, regularized

I'm following an online tutorial on neural networks, [neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com) The writer, Nielsen, implemented L2-regularization in the code as a part of this tutorial. Now he asks us to modify the code in such a way that it uses L1-regularization instead of L2. This [link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#eqtn97) will take you straight to the part of the tutorial I am talking about.

The weight update rule with L2-regularization using Stochastic gradient descent is as follows: 
[image: Weight update-rule with L2-regularization]

And Nielsen implements it in python as such:

```
self.weights = [(1-eta*(lmbda/n))*w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
```

The update rule with L1-regularization becomes:

[image: Weight update-rule with L1- regularization]

And I tried to implement it as follows:

```
self.weights = [(w - eta* (lmbda/len(mini_batch)) * np.sign(w) - (eta/len(mini_batch)) * nw)
                 for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
```

Suddenly my neural network has a classification accuracy of +- chance... **How can this be?** Did i make a mistake in my implementation of L1-regularization? I have a neural network with 30 hidden neurons, learning rate of 0.5 and lambda = 5.0. When I use the L2 regularization everything is fine.

For your convenience please find the entire update function here:

```
def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta, lmbda, n):
    """Update the network's weights and biases by applying gradient
    descent using backpropagation to a single mini batch.  The
    ``mini_batch`` is a list of tuples ``(x, y)``, ``eta`` is the
    learning rate, ``lmbda`` is the regularization parameter, and
    ``n`` is the total size of the training data set.

    """
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
    self.weights = [(1-eta*(lmbda/n))*w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw      
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]
```

Comment: any loop in python also array operations like zip have poor performance

Comment: oh its about values, try to decreace reg. amount

Comment: I tried, to no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the math wrong. The translation in code of the formula you want to implement is:

```
self.weights = [
    (w - eta * (lmbda / n) * np.sign(w) - eta * nabla_b[0])
    for w in self.weights]
```

The two required modifications are:

- removing the dependency on the mini-batch size
- use only the first *nabla* coefficient